# How do I fix this problem with multiplying two matrices?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two matrices, the two matrices are read rom a text file, which is why the values of the matrices are not initialized. This is the code:

```
int main() {
    ...
    else if (multiplication == true){
        if (columnsA == rowsB && rowsA == columnsB){
            for(int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < columnsB + 1; j++){
                    for(int k = 0; k < columnsA; k++){
                        C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("\nError: The number of columns in Matrix A must be equal to the number of rows in Matrix B for multiplication");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    ...

return 0;
}
```

`A` is the first matrix, `B` is the second matrix and `C` is the output. `rowsA` is the number of rows in matrix `A` and columns `B` is the number of columns in `matrixB`.

**The code works for the first numbers in the ouput matrix, but the last number always ends up being a very long random number.**

For example the input will be a `2x2` matrix with the following values:
Row 1: 3 1
Row 2: 5 2

and another `2x2` matrix with the following values

```
row 1: 4 1
row 2: 2 6
```

The output comes out as

```
row 1: 14 9
row 2: 24 -374793898(or some other long, random number)
```

The first three number are correct (I checked) **but the last one is never right.**

Comment: The code seems correct. It sounds to me that you are not filling up correctly one of  the matrices (A, B and/or C) before multiplying them

Comment: Note that the test `rowsA == columsB` is useless. Matrix `C` is not obliged to be square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root cause is this line

```
for(int j = 0; j < columnsB + 1; j++){
```

The +1 makes you go outside the 5x5 matrix

Also you really need to initialize the C matrix to 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
   else if (multiplication == true){
        if (columnsA == rowsB && rowsA == columnsB){
            for(int i = 0; i < rowsA; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < columnsB + 1; j++){
                    for(int k = 0; k < columnsA; k++){
                        C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
```

Your multiplication code reads the values from the matrices `C`, `A` and `B`. Matrices A and B are read from file, however you forgot to initialize the matrix `C` with zeros (*i.e.,* `int C[5][5] = {0};`). Otherwise, matrix C will contain *random* values. And those random values will be added to the matrices `A` and `B` during the operation  `C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];`.

Moreover, change `columnsB + 1` to `columnsB`, in `for(int j = 0; j < columnsB + 1; j++)`. Otherwise, you are going out of the boundaries of the matrix `C` and `B`, marked in the following code with "^":

```
 for(int j = 0; j < columnsB + 1; j++)
    for(int k = 0; k < columnsA; k++)
        C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                      ^^^                 ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this,

Initialize the c[5][5] with 0.